# Wpf Textblock width changes when i input multiple lines of text

Tags: c#, wpf, scale, textblock

Hello im trying to make my text on the button use all the space available and stay scalable.

this is my current code

```
<Button x:Name="ButtonTest" Grid.Column="5" Margin="5" Style="{DynamicResource FunctionButton}">
    <Button.Content>
        <Viewbox x:Name="ViewTest">
            <TextBlock Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ButtonTest}" 
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text="Test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test test"></TextBlock>
        </Viewbox>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

with my code if i input enough text to make multiple lines the width reduces.

[image]

I can manually set my width of the textblock and produce this. so why does not the binding work when i enter multiple lines.

[image]

Style used

```
<Style x:Key="FunctionButtonBase" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource NormalFontBrush}"></Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="FunctionButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource FunctionButtonBase}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource NormalButtonBrush}"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: May be you sould set the HorizontalAlignment and/or HorizontalContentAlignment of the ViewBox and/or the TextBlock ?

Comment: HorizontalAlignment as Stretch does no difference, i dont know how i set HorizontalContentAlignment i'll have to read about that one :)

Comment: @Dennis: Ahh i didnt think of the style. i can play around with that. i updated the question with the style

Comment: @Dennis: Are you sure it works without the style? i cant make it work

Comment: @Dendei it won't work with `ViewBox` which will take `TextBlock` actual rectangle and scale it (up or down) to fit available rectangle. What you need is is some sort of `FontSize` custom converter that would down size text if it does not fit

Comment: @bit: Setting HorizontalContentAlignment on the button seemed to make the viewbox width correct but not the textblock. and i dont think i can set that property on an viewbox?

Comment: @Dendei: sorry, I've missed size settings for button.

Comment: So not clear. "so why does not the binding work when i enter multiple lines."  You don't show your binding nor is it clear to me just what is not working.

Comment: @Blam: how can i not be clear? i set the binding here <TextBlock Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=ButtonTest}" And if you look at the pictures you'll se that the width is reduced when i enter text that makes multiple lines. and on the last picture i manually set the width and then it looks better. which i want my binding to do instead so i get good scalability.

Comment: to clarify more the two last pictures (the one of the three most to the right, and the one the the bottom) have the same text, only when i set my width manually i get the full width and the text can be larger, and easier to see.

Comment: For one you don't define manually set.  You don't have a single answer.